# Looping for loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

i want to looping an array then enter the value into the variable.

and i got an error :

> ErrorException in PageController.php line 324: Undefined offset: 3

this is my code :

```
for ($i=0;$i<$hasil["response_data"];$i++){
                    //ambil data array dri WS 
                    $lowonganid =$hasil["response_data"][$i]["id"]."</br>";
                    $jabatan_lw = $hasil["response_data"][$i]["jabatan"]."</br>";
                    $pptkis_lw = $hasil["response_data"][$i]["pptkis"]."</br>";
                    $agency_lw = $hasil["response_data"][$i]["agency"]."</br>";
                    $negara_lw = $hasil["response_data"][$i]["negara"];
                    $gaji_awal_lw = $hasil["response_data"][$i]["gaji_awal"];
                    $gaji_akhir_lw = $hasil["response_data"][$i]["gaji_akhir"]."</br>";
                    $totaljob_lw = $hasil["response_data"][$i]["totaljob"]."</br>";
                    $expired_infoKerja_lw = $hasil["response_data"][$i]["expired"]."</br>";
                }
                echo $lowonganid;
                exit;
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: If you want to iterate an array then always try to use the 'foreach' method instead of for loop.

Comment: `$i<$hasil["response_data"]` will use the _value_ of `$hasil["response_data"]` when you probably mean the _count_:`count($hasil["response_data"])`. However, as suggested, `foreach()` will probably suite you better. Also, you're currently overwriting the variables in each iteration so only the values from the last iteration will be available after the loop. What's the expected result here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be of help for you:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($hasil["response_data"]); $i++){

}
```

OR

Use for each:

```
foreach ($hasil["response_data"] as $key => $value) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should count, I guess that  => $hasil["response_data"] is an array
So use count($hasil["response_data"]) in the for loop;

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($hasil["response_data"]);$i++)
```